# Why is my data binding not working and is always null?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am trying to add data to the database. I experimenting with `Blazor` and `.NET core`:

This is my code in the controller:

```
 [Route("AddCarBlazor")]
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostBlazor(Car car)
        {
            if (car.CarId == 0)
            {
                // New
                car.Created = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Cars.Add(car);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                // Update
                var c = _context.Cars.First(e => e.CarId == car.CarId);
                c.Brand = car.Brand;
                c.Color = car.Color;
                c.Model = car.Model;
                c.LastChange = DateTime.Now;
                c.TopSpeed = car.TopSpeed;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok();
            }
        }
```

My **car** model looks like this:

```
public class Car
    {
        [Key]
        public long CarId { get; set; }
        public string Created { get; set; }
        public string LastChange { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public long TopSpeed { get; set; }
    }
```

I call this method like this:

```
  private async Task AddCar()
    {
        await Http.PostJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/AddCarBlazor/", carobject);
        await Refresh();
    }
```

When I fill in the form and press **add** button the **car object** is always **null**

This is my form with the databinding:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Brand</label>
            <input input type="text" @bind="@carobject.Brand" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter brand" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Model</label>
            <input type="text" @bind="@carobject.Model" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter model" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Color</label>
            <input type="text" @bind="@carobject.Color" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter color" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>TopSpeed</label>
            <input type="number" @bind="@carobject.TopSpeed" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter speed" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group mr-2">
        <button class="btn btn-danger mr-1" onclick=@AddCar>Save changes</button>       
    </div>
</form>
```

I have put a breakpoint on the **addCar** method. I get the values from the fields but when it goes to the controller it becomes **null**.

I have following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0

How can I save the values from the fields and send it to the database?

Comment: You should include the code for AddCar() because that is where it goed wrong. You Blazor databinding works, the REST part doesn't.

Comment: Where do I have to include it? In the **Startup.cs** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a weekend of research I have the solution!

I have changed my method in **CarService.cs** like this:

```
public async Task AddCar(Car car)
{
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44369/api/car/") };
        await client.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "AddCar", car);
}
```

Then I call this method in my razor page like this:

```
async Task AddCar()
{
    await CarService.AddCar(car);
    car = new CarService.Car();
    await LoadCarData();
}
```

I also made a new object of the service like this:

```
CarService.Car car = new CarService.Car();
```

And I moved the model of **Car.cs** into **CarService.cs**

Answer (score 1):

I test a demo which works well, you could refer to my code below:

1.Car.cs (namespace Blazor.Models)

```
public class Car
{

    public long CarId { get; set; }       
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

}
```

2. AddCar.razor

```
@page "/car"

@using System.Net.Http
@inject HttpClient Http
@using Blazor.Models

<Editform Model="carobject">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Brand</label>
            <input   @bind="@carobject.Brand" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter brand" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Model</label>
            <input  @bind="@carobject.Model" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter model" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group mr-2">
        <button class="btn btn-danger mr-1" onclick="@AddCar">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</Editform>

@functions {


[Parameter]
private Car carobject { get; set; } = new Car();

private async Task AddCar()
{       
    await Http.PostJsonAsync(baseUrl + "/AddCarBlazor/", carobject);
    //await Refresh();

}
}
```

3.Web API CORS configuration:

```
 app.UseCors(corsbuilder => {
            corsbuilder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
        });

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseMvc();
```

4.action:

```
[Route("AddCarBlazor")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostBlazor([FromBody]Car car)
```